# Datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, date-formatting

how do I convert a datetime to look like "dd/MM/yyyy" in a stored procedure?

Comment: As opposed to least possible answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 103) – dd/mm/yyyy
```

and see other format from here http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/